# Vb.Net generic dictionary, how to I add values

Tags: vb.net, generics, dictionary

I have a class defined that is built on a Generic Dictionary.

```
Partial Public Class DictionaryFromExcel(Of tValue)
    Private _Dictionary As Dictionary(Of String, tValue)
```

tValue can be a numeric type or string. Everything works fine until I try to add an item to the dictionary.

```
If GetType(tValue) = GetType(String) Then
    _Dictionary.Add(key, _Row.Cell(StartColumnIndex).GetFormattedString)
Else
    _Dictionary.Add(key, _Row.Cell(StartColumnIndex).GetFormattedString.FromPercent)
End If
```

I get an error "Value of type 'String' or 'Decimal' cannot be converted to iValue. I have tried Cast and DirectCast but get similar errors.

Comment: what is that even trying to do? Can you take a step back, and tell us the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You might want to show us your definition of `tValue` as well.

Comment: I have a very complex function that reads two columns of Excel files and returns a Dictionary. The first column is always a string, the second could be any type (String, Integer, Decimal, Boolean). I don't want to create multiple versions of the function when they mostly vary by 1 line.

Comment: Dim x As New DictionaryFromExcel(Of Decimal) (Column1, Column2, StartRow)